# Unittesting pomless aspectJ project

Tags: aspectj, tycho, aspectj-maven-plugin, tycho-surefire-plugin

In a Tycho build I have a pomless plugin-project/bundle A with some aspectj classes in it (*.aj). The project builds fine and another project B can reference project A via its manifest.mf. 
Now a separate unittest project C exists for testing project A. This unittest project C is intended to be build with standard pom.xml and maven-surefire (no manifest.mf exists in C).

The problem is that C cannot find the *.aj classes of project A. If I introduce a pom.xml in project A with maven-aspectj-plugin then A can be build and C finds anything it needs in A. But then project B cannot find bundle A. Are there any suggestions to resolve such a problem?

I'm relativly new to Tycho and i assume the problem belongs to the mix of the pom-less approach in project A and the pom-based approach in unittest project C. Is there any possibility to build the mentioned unitest project C pom-based or do i need to build it with tycho-surefire ?

I found this related question
[Aspectj class is not found by test class when running test with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52986728/aspectj-class-is-not-found-by-test-class-when-running-test-with-maven)
but it didn't help for me in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pom.xml should be used in project A, with packaging type eclipse-plugin, no dependencies set, and the usual plugin setup of aspectj-maven-plugin